# How can I find tournaments which are not full?

Tags: clash-royale

I have visited the tournament view for several times now, but everytime the complete list of tournaments was full with occupied tournaments.

Do I have to be very quick or do I do something wrong?
Is there maybe a way to refresh the list with a new list?

Comment: Hint: The loupe in the top right corner can be used for refreshing even without a search string. Did not notice that in the beginning.

Comment: What the hell is super cell doing making tournaments impossible to join?

Comment: http://howsmyclan.com/OpenClashRoyaleTournaments/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep on scrolling my friend. There seems to not be a filter as of yet. I couldn't find an empty one myself, so I just kept refreshing it. I allowed my location, etc and I got into one quite quickly.

Update: Just keep refreshing the page, as soon as you seen an orange tournament (not just started) don't think don't look, just try to join.

Comment: http://howsmyclan.com/OpenClashRoyaleTournaments/

Answer (score 5):

I find the solution and 100% worked for me try this method hope it helps you too:
Source:http://www.gammerson.com/2016/07/open-tournament-clash-royale-trick.html

Solution from the link:

- Searching for *weird* names in the top search box, example:

  > "Let me in"
- bad example:

  > "open", "free join", ...

Comment: When providing an answer it's a good idea to include the relevant content from any links that are crucial to your answer. That way, if the link ever goes dead, your answer will still be meaningful.

Comment: Sure ! will do it next time !

Answer (score 4):

Search for "pass" or "password". Some people include the password in the name, that's how i joined.

Comment: howsmyclan.com/OpenClashRoyaleTournaments

Answer (score 3):

Another approach that can be used: search for random words. I got bored refreshing the tournament page, so started typing in words into the search bar (e.g., "Nexus"). The search results go beyond the "tournaments in your area" limitation, and I was able to find an open one - hosted in India of all places.

Comment: howsmyclan.com/OpenClashRoyaleTournaments